# How to copy files of a certain type in python

Tags: python

I have a folder (with other subfolders) from which i would like to copy only the .js files to another existing folder (this also has subfolders with the same folder structure as the first one, except this one has only the folders, so no file)

How can i do that with python? I tried shutil.copytree but it fails because some folders already exists.

Comment: Why do you need python for this?

Comment: what system do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `os.path.splitext` or `glob.iglob`

```
glob.iglob(pathname)
```

> Return an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without
>   actually storing them all simultaneously.

I propose a solution with `os.path.splitext`, walking with `os.walk`. I make use of `os.path.relpath` to find relative path in the duplicate tree.

`source_dir` is your source uppermost source folder, `dest_dir` your uppermost destination folder.

```
import os, shutil, glob

source_dir = "F:\CS\PyA"
dest_dir = "F:\CS\PyB"

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
    for file in filenames:
        (shortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(file)
        if extension == ".txt" :
            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root,file), os.path.join(dest_dir,   
                         os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root,file),source_dir)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from glob import glob
from shutil import copy
import os

def copyJS(src, dst):
    listing = glob(src + '/*')
    for f in listing:
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            lastToken = f.split('/')[-1]
            copyJS(src+'/' + lastToken, dst+ '/' + lastToken)
        elif f[-3:] == '.js':
            copy(f, dst)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using copy2 it's better to preserve all the metadata of each file.

Comment: Sometimes it is better and sometimes it isn't necessary. Performing the copystat() is not a zero-resource command. Though the original poster is certainly welcome to use copy2 if they like.